# SSH fails to start when ListenAddress is set to Wireguard VPN IP

Tags: systemd, sshd, wireguard

Suppose I have a a wireguard network called `wg0` on `10.0.0.1/24`.  I use systemd to start it on boot:

```
# systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0
```

I want sshd to only listen on the wireguard address, `10.0.0.1`, instead of `0.0.0.0`.  So I set the `ListenAddress` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ListenAddress  10.0.0.1
#ListenAddress  ::
AddressFamily  inet
```

**Note**: *I set the address family because I'm only using IPv4 and not IPv6 here.  I think if it's not set, ssh will continue to listen to `::` on IPv6.*

If I save the config and restart sshd, it works great.  But after the server restarts, ssh fails to start, despite being enabled in systemd.  The syslog output tells us why:

```
sshd[xxx]: error: Bind to port 22 on 10.0.0.1 failed: Cannot assign requested address.
```

Clearly, we have a race condition where sshd is trying (and failing) to start before the wireguard interface is ready.

The obvious solution is to edit `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service` and add `wg-quick@wg0` as a dependency.  However, no combination of `After=`, `Wants=`, or `Requires=` does the trick.  It seems that `wg-quick@wg0` reports that it's finished, even though the network interface isn't actually ready yet.

Answer (score 6):

Systemd will wait for the interface to be ready if `sys-devices-virtual-net-XXX.device` is listed as a dependency.  So to have sshd wait for the wg0 interface, add these lines to the `[Unit]` section of `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service`:

```
After=network.target wg-quick@wg0.service
Requires=sys-devices-virtual-net-wg0.device
```

This should work for any service listening on a wireguard address.  SSH also requires `After=auditd.service`.  Items in `After=` can be space seperated or be on multiple `After=` lines.

Finally, reload the daemon and restart the service:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: Note you can use `systemctl edit sshd` and then add a `[Unit]` block and the lines above; then you won't need to make modifications to the built-in service file, and you don't need to execute a `daemon-reload`.

Comment: I was having another issue with `dnsmasq`, but this line `Requires=sys-devices-virtual-net-wg0.device` helped me there too. Thanks for the great tip!